# Is there some way to use @Html.HiddenFor for complete model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

Is there a way to use (or something simular)

```
  @Html.HiddenFor
```

for your whole model.

So instead of doing something like this:

```
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Person.Name)
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Person.LastName)
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Address.Street)
```

use something like this (this example doesn't work)

```
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model)
```

I've already searched for it on stackoverflow and google...but haven't found anything about it.

I need to hold on to some values for different models that aren't saved into db, so using only Html.HiddenFor the ID is not an option for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't want to do this! You should only have the Primary Key of the entity passed, then look it back up server side... otherwise the client can change their address etc. If you don't save them to DB but need them to persist, use session or cookies or localstorage or something instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the properties you want to be in a hidden input and add the `HiddenInputAttribute` in your model as follows:

```cs
public class MyModel
{
    [HiddenInput]
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Darin & @ Haythem thanks, i will test both answers end of these week!

Answer (score 3):

You may take a look at the [MVCContrib's Html.Serialize method](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/03/06/persisting-model-state-in-asp-net-mvc-using-html-serialize.aspx). It's sorta viewstate emulation (and internally it indeed uses ViewState :-)).

An alternative approach would be to simply store an unique id as a hidden field and inside the controller action use this id to fetch the corresponding model from your underlying data store.