# Model not being passed to rendered view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

I am having an issue getting data in my model on my MakePayment.cshmtl view.

The AccountScreen.cshtml is calling the MakePayment.cshtml view:

```
@model SuburbanCustPortal.SuburbanService.CustomerData      

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Account Screen";
 }

<h2>AccountScreen</h2>

<div class="leftdiv">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>customer info</legend>
    @Html.Partial("CustomerInfoPartialView", Model)
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>delivery address</legend>
    @Html.Partial("DeliveryAddressPartialView", Model)
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>delivery info</legend>
    @Html.Partial("DeliveryInfoPartialView", Model)
  </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="rightdiv">
  <fieldset> 
    <legend>balance</legend>
    <div>
      @Html.Partial("BalancePartialView", Model)
    </div>    
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset> 
    <legend>payment</legend>
    <div>
      @Html.Partial("MakePayment", Model)
    </div>    
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset> 
    <legend>billing info</legend>
    <div>
      @Html.Partial("BillingInfoPartialView", Model)
    </div>    
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

My MakePayment.cshtml view:

```
@model SuburbanCustPortal.SuburbanService.CustomerData

  @using (Html.BeginForm("MakePayment2", "Customer", FormMethod.Post))
  {
    <div style="text-align:center;">
      <input class="makePaymentInput" type="submit" value="Make a Payment" />
    </div>       
  }
```

My CustomerController:

```
public ActionResult AccountScreen(LogOnModel model)
{
  return ShowCustomer(model.AccountNumber);
}

public ActionResult MakePayment(CustomerData model)
{
  return View("MakePayment", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MakePayment2(CustomerData model)
{
  //CustomerData model = new CustomerData();
  var newmodel = new PaymentModel.SendToGateway();
  newmodel.AccountBalance = model.TotalBalance;
  newmodel.Amount = model.TotalBalance;

  return RedirectToAction("PrePayment", "Payment", newmodel);
}
```

The `public ActionResult MakePayment(CustomerData model)` is never being reached.

**My problem:** The `[HttpPost] public ActionResult MakePayment2(CustomerData model)` is being reached but the model has nulls in it.

I know the data initial model from the AccountScreen is being populated since the other views that are being rendered is showing data.

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965096/is-there-some-way-to-use-html-hiddenfor-for-complete-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is there's nothing inside your form except a submit button.  You need to make sure input fields are there (either text boxes, select lists, or hidden fields), as those are what post data back to the controller.

You could try using `EditorForModel` inside your partial view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MakePayment2", "Customer", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <div style="text-align:center;">
      <input class="makePaymentInput" type="submit" value="Make a Payment" />
    </div>       
}
```

---

**Edit based on comments**

Razor doesn't include an `Html.HiddenForModel()` method, for whatever reason.  Possible workarounds:

- List out each property of the model using `Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Property)`
- [Annotate the model properties with `\[HiddenInput\]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7965140/1001985)
- Use `EditorForModel()` but wrap it in `<div style="display: none;"></div>` (NOTE that a malicious user can still modify the properties as if they were visible.)
- [Use only `Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)` and fetch the model in the controller.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7965116/1001985)
- Use the serialization method in the [MVC Futures assembly](http://nuget.org/packages/Mvc3Futures)

Related quesion here:

- [Is there some way to use @Html.HiddenFor for complete model?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7965096/1001985)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I understand why now although using EditorForModel displays ALL of my fields on the screen which is an issue. How do I send my model in the post?

Comment: @ErocM just use the other HTML helpers.  `HiddenFor` for the ones you don't want displayed, and `EditorFor` for the others:  `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Field1)`, etc.

Comment: I take it there isn't a way to pass the model? I have quite a few fields.

Comment: @ErocM maybe wrap `EditorForModel()` in a `<div style='display: none;'>` (should "work", but may not be acceptable for you depending on the scenario)...

Comment: @ErocM I found another question related to this -- no one there could come up with a simple way to do `Html.HiddenForModel()` (unless you want to modify the annotation attributes on your model, which I'm guessing you don't).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965096/is-there-some-way-to-use-html-hiddenfor-for-complete-model

Comment: @ErocM although, maybe Darin's link on that thread could work for you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965096/is-there-some-way-to-use-html-hiddenfor-for-complete-model

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, you are creating a form containing nothing else than a submit button.

When you submit it, it posts nothing back to the server, thus your function receives an empty model.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MakePayment2", "Customer", FormMethod.Post))
  {
    <div style="text-align:center;">
      <input class="makePaymentInput" type="submit" value="Make a Payment" />
    </div>       
  }
```

This translates as :

```
<form method="POST" action="{url}">
    <div style="text-align:center;">
      <input class="makePaymentInput" type="submit" value="Make a Payment" />
    </div>
</form>
```

***More details :***

Since in the logic you then redirect to a new page to collect payment information, you don't want to give the user the opportunity to *mess* with your model, thus you should query your customer data from your Context instead of trusting what is submitted in the POST.

Thus all you really need to add if this :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MakePayment2", "Customer", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.{ID Field})
   <div style="text-align:center;">
     <input class="makePaymentInput" type="submit" value="Make a Payment" />
   </div>       
}
```

This way, you will be able to get your model back in the server side code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand what is wrong now but how I send the model in the post now?

Comment: I added some details, the trick is not necessarily to pass the whole object back to the Controler. You just need a way to retrieve the right information.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your form submits nothing as there are no input fields inside the form scope. Try to wrap all your html in `AccountScreen.cshtml` within `@using (Html.BeginForm(` statement (and throw it out from `MakePayment.cshtml`).