# Pass Model to controller using Html.HiddenFor

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

At form submission, I am using `@Html.HiddenFor(a => a.ModelParameter)` to hold all of the values as it makes its way to the controller. My question is, for Models that have many parameters (25+) is there a better way to pass all of those parameters using `@Html.HiddenFor`?

For example,

`foreach(var parameter in Model)
 {
   @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem.parameter)
 }`

Or something along these lines to avoid having to do an individual `@Html.HiddenFor` for every single parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set an attribute on the properties that are supposed to be hidden.

[Is there some way to use @Html.HiddenFor for complete model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965096/is-there-some-way-to-use-html-hiddenfor-for-complete-model)