# ViewModel not posting back in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The models in my viewmodel is always NULL when posting back.

Please see my codes:

Here is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(long? id)
{
    if (id == null) 
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Query query = db.Queries.Find(id);
    if (query == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    var viewModel = new QueryViewModel(query);

    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create (QueryViewModel viewModel, string Message)
{
    //viewmodel processing here
    //viewModel.Query is always null here


    return View();
}
```

Here is the view:

```
@model ViewModels.QueryViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Query)
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Post a reply</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-control textarea size12">
            @Html.TextArea("Message")
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" value="Post Reply"/>
    </div>
}
```

Here are the 2 models and the viewmodel:

```
public class Query 
{
    public long QueryID {get;set;}
    /**
     * some properties goes here...
     **/
}

public class QueryReply
{
    public long QueryReplyID {get;set;}
    public long QueryID {get;set;}
    /**
     * some properties goes here...
     **/

    public virtual Query Query {get;set;}
}

public class QueryViewModel 
{
    public Query Query {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<QueryReply> QueryReplies {get;set;}

    public QueryViewModel() {}

    public QueryViewModel (Query query)
    {
        Query = query;
    }
}
```

Please help, Thanks!

**--EDIT--**

Additionally, if I will name the model Query in my ViewModel as 'Query', on postback the viewModel.Query will still be NULL. But if I will change the name of Query Model in my ViewModel as 'QueryModel' (or any other name aside from Query) the viewModel.QueryModel will have a value. Please can you explain why is this happening? Thanks again..

Comment: You cant use `@Html.HiidenFor()` for a complex property (look at the html your generating!) You need to generate controls for each property you want to post. But you should be using a view model (a view model contains only those properties you need to edit/display in a view - its not for holding other data models)

Comment: Regarding your edit. you cannot have a parameter named the same as a model property name. If your posting (say) `Query: "SomeValue"` the `DefaultModelBinder` finds the parameter `Query`(which is a complex object) and tries to set it to the value "SomeValue" which of course fails (you cant set a complex object to a string) and the parameter becomes null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What does your HTML form look like?

I suspect `Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Query)` to not print anything. You need to print specific model properties:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Query.QueryID)
```

See also [Is there some way to use @Html.HiddenFor for complete model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965096/is-there-some-way-to-use-html-hiddenfor-for-complete-model).

Comment: Gonna check that, will get back to you in a while, Thanks!

Comment: That's it! It's just a developer's issue LOL, lack of sleep! Thanks a lot CodeCaster! 8 mins to accept your answer.

Comment: I have a property Query Query {get;set;} in my viewModel right? On my postback in Create action in my controller, viewModel.Query still NULL. But if I will change the property to Query QueryModel {get;set;} , viewModel.QueryModel.QueryID will have a value. Hope I explain it clearly. Thanks again

Comment: I'm not sure that only that change in the code you've shown will cause that behavior, especially not with `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Query)`. Again, verify what HTML is being generated. Then you can see what names MVC uses, so you know what to handle in your POST (or vice versa).